# Discord.py How to keep track of all guilds

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have a discord bot and I want this discord bot only on my servers so I created a new status task that goes trough the servers and leaves other servers. The problem is that .guilds only updates every time I run the script. I highly appreciate every new solution or way to fix this issue. Have a good day.

```
async def Join_Protection():
    global PROTECTION
    global Verified_Servers
    Verified_Servers = []
    ProtecFile = open('SaveServers.txt', 'r')
    while True:
        time.sleep(0.5)
        print(client.guilds)
        for i in client.guilds:
            id = i.id
            if str(id) not in ProtecFile.readlines():
                print('Left unverified Server: {} | Id: {}'.format(i, id))
                await i.leave()
            else:
                if id not in Verified_Servers:
                    print('Verified Server: {} | Id: {}'.format(i, id))
                    Verified_Servers.append(i)
```

Comment: If you don't want your bot on others servers, why not just disable "Public Bot" in the developer portal? Quote: "When unchecked, only you can join this bot to servers."

Comment: I want other people to be able to invite the bot

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`client.on_guild_join`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.on_guild_join) event. It is triggered everytime the bot is added to a new guild.

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_join(guild):
    ProtecFile = open('SaveServers.txt', 'r')
    if str(guild.id) not in ProtecFile.readlines():
        await guild.leave()

    ProtecFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks thats a good idea. I'll look into that!